# How to switch off backward auto correction?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, autocorrect

Auto-Correction is disabled in Settings > General > Keyboards.

But the keyboard still auto corrects!?

I swipe [word 1], then [word 2] and suddenly [word 1] changes. It btw never ever changes to something that makes any sense whatsoever.

(iOS 15.7.1)

Answer (score 0):

This function might fall under **Predictive Text** in the same area of settings.

Edit: after reading many Apple support forum posts, it seems like one thing you can do is reset your keyboard dictionary. Judging by the posts, this method is hit or miss. It seems like Apple crowdsources common phrases and automatically replaces certain phrases with others if people commonly do that manually. I still believe this would fall under predictive text.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer?  As written, it’s more of a comment than an answer.  It’s important to provide context so it helps readers better understand how it solves the problem.

Comment: _IF_ that is true then that would be inconvenient as "Predictive" also is the word suggestion function which is useful.

Comment: @Allan Unfortunately I don’t have the ability to comment yet, otherwise I would have written a comment. But just going from what OP stated, I went into my settings and looked at what might cause this behavior assuming it wasn’t Autocorrect, and the only other thing that makes sense is Predictive Text.

Comment: You gain the ability to comment by having answers up voted. What I am suggesting is that you improve the *answer*.

Comment: @allan, I just did that